# How to handle a variable in HTML?

Tags: python, html, variables, flask

I have the following flask application that displays a dashboard with various buttons. Each button executes a python function. After the execution of such a function I want the application to return to the dashboard. In order to give the user a simple log I want to output some string on the html page. For that thought about a tag above the buttons on the dashboard that get filled with the respective value. How can I do that?

**Flask:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/something')
def do_something():
    print("Hello")
    return render_template('index.html', user="Successfully executed!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <title>MP Reporting</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div value=user></div>
    <a href="./something">Your button</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem with current scenario? do you see any error?

Comment: You have a template. Rendering variables is what they do. Have you read any of the Jinja2 documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flask template use "{{kwarg}}" i.e. in your example

```
<div>{{user}}</div>
```

will render as

```
<div>Successfully executed!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print variables using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).
To print out the variable `user` in your example add

`{{ user }}`  in the html template.

If you send a list of items to the html you can output them by using a simple for:

```
{% for item in items %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But I leave the python function as it is?

Comment: @user3080315 Yes, you send variables to the template by defining them like you did and then you can use them in the html using jinja2

Comment: @user3080315 hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, I suggest using Flask's built-in message flashing which is simpler, and neater instead of passing variables to render_template manually. It's simple as that:

(template)

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

(flask view)

```
from flask import flash

flash("Successfully executed!")
```

You can get more information from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/).